# vim nmap very strange behavior

Tags: vim

I have some nmap in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap ( ()<Esc>i
nnoremap [ []<Esc>i
nnoremap { {}<Esc>i
```

The '(' works fine. If I type '(' I'll get '()'. But if I type '[' or '{' I'll get 3 additional space characters between the '[' and ']'.

I have no idea what cause this behavior. I'm wandering how can I trace the nmap process so I can catch the bug.

Comment: How does this work? You are using `nnoremap` not `inoremap`.

Comment: Sorry for mistype imap to nmap! : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have trailing white space in your nnoremap (or inoremap) commands. Remove them.

You can check this by doing `:set list` and looking at where the `$` or end of line character is.

The trailing whitespace is made part of the mapping and since the mapping is supposed to place the cursor in the middle of the brackets the extra whitespace is put there.